# ubuntu 20.04 settings not opening

Tags: 20.04, gnome

Whenever I tried to open my ubuntu settings, the gnome control window doesn't open anymore. I reinstalled it again, but when I try to execute the command below, it's shows the following message.

I used this command to reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall gnome-control-center
```

If I execute this command or any command that uses gnome-control-central

```
gnome-control-center display
```

I got the following message:

> gnome-control-center: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libldb.so.2: version `LDB_2.2.3' not found (required by /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/samba/libsamdb-common.so.0)

Comment: 20.04 is getting a bit old, but here is a discussion: would have been caused by a bug in samba packaging: https://groups.google.com/g/linux.debian.bugs.dist/c/jWaVTy2UVSE. Maybe also try reinstalling the package libldb (the same way you did for gnome-control-center)